# How do I add another Logon Account for Windows Azure Management Portal?

Tags: azure, authentication, portal, account, administrator

I need to create a separate Account for the Windows Azure Management Portal so I can allow someone else to login and deploy maintain the account, but be able to remove the ability to login if needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by:

- Logging into the Azure Management Portal
- Select `Settings` on the bottom left
- Select `Administrators` at the top of the screen
- Click `+ Add` at the bottom of the screen
- Enter a **Windows Live ID** or **Microsoft Account** into the Email Address column

  - You can create a live account with an existing email [here](https://signup.live.com/signup.aspx?lic=1)
- Select the Subscription(s) you want available to the user
- Click `OK`

Poof! You're done!

You can find the full article  [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg456328.aspx)

Comment: How do you login to azure portal once your windows login is associated with different organizations. I see selection. When I login it just goes to my personal azure portal.